# Find a basis for the subspace spanned by $S$ in $M_{2,2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I wanted to make sure I am doing this problem correctly.

$S = \langle \begin{bmatrix}2&0\\-3&0\\ \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}-4&6\\3&3\\ \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&2\\-1&1\\ \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}4&6\\-9&3\\ \end{bmatrix}\rangle$

I went and found the rref:

$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & -3 & 0\\-4 & 6 & 3 & 3\\0 & 2 & -1 & 1\\4 & 6 & -9 & 3 \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow (...) \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -\frac{3}{2} & 0\\0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Would this be the basis?

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\-\frac{3}{2}&0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 &1\\-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}$$

And then how would I go about finding the dimension of the subspace?

Comment: You want to be careful. The only reason why your answer is correct because you unraveled each $2\times 2$ matrix into a *row* of a $4\times 4$ matrix rather than a column. Applying the $\text{rref}$ operation yields a matrix with an equivalent row space but not necessarily an equivalent column space. If you happened to write these four matrices as four columns instead four rows you would get $$\text{rref}\begin{pmatrix}2&-4&0&4\\ \:0&6&2&6\\ \:-3&3&-1&-9\\ \:0&3&1&3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&\frac{2}{3}&4\\ \:0&1&\frac{1}{3}&1\\ \:0&0&0&0\\ \:0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: You *cannot* say that $\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}\Bigg\}$ is a basis for $\text{span}(S)$ since the column spaces in the two $4 \times 4$ matrices above are different. To avoid any and all complications of this sort you should identify the independent columns of your reduced matrix and correspond them to the appropriate matrices in your expression of $S$.

Comment: That being said, I would say a safer (but no less accurate) answer to your question is $$\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ -3&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-4&6\\ 3&3\end{pmatrix}\Bigg\}$$ The dimension of $\text{span}(S)$ happens to be $2$ since you have two linearly independent vectors in your basis.

Comment: Who is M2,2 in the title? It does not seem to appear in the question itself.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I assumed it's the space of all $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries.

Comment: @MatthewPilling In that case, how does $S$ enter into the question of the title? Why not give the "standard" basis of all 4 elementary matrices for $M_{2,2}$? I think the title of the question is incomplete.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I think the OP is in the initial stages of learning terms like "span" and "subspace". The problem is clearly meant to find a basis for the span of $S$ but this wasn't properly communicated.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I appreciate your help. If I may ask, could an answer also be $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\-\frac{2}{3}&4 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 &1\\\frac{1}{3}&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  But as commented it is good to recall that the linearly independent columns of the RREF correspond to the linearly independent columns of the original matrix, and do not in themselves generally constitute a basis.
You probably just lucked out by writing them as rows, since row spaces are preserved by elementary row operations.  (All of this can be hard, for me at least, to recall, and @MatthewPilling has helped us remember in the comments).

And since there are two elements in the basis, the dimension is $2$.  The rank, alternatively, of the RREF is two.